# Javascript cookie value is lost after loading another page

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I have a page with a hidden form where a value is echoed by php.

With javascript/jQuery I pick up the value and store it in a cookie. The user is redirected to an external page, then is redirected back to my site on a different page. On this page the cookie value is "0" (the value is lost).

**Update**:  The last page is in a directory above the page where the cookie is set. I set the "path" on the cookie but it still doesn't work.

So - first I do the redirect (by submitting a form) , then I set the cookie:

```
function sendPostRequest(){
    var $ = jQuery;

    document.myform.submit(); //submitting the form

    var now = new Date();
    var time = now.getTime();
    time += 144000 * 1000;
    now.setTime(time);
    document.cookie =
        'member_id=' + $('#member_input').val() + //getting the value, setting the cookie
        '; expires=' + now.toUTCString() +
        '; path=http://domain-name/the-last-page/';

    console.log(document.cookie); //the cookie is set
    alert($('#member_input').val());
}
```

The cookie is set as it should after the redirect.

When the user comes back from the external page to the new page , it shows `member_id=0` . So the value is lost.

I suspect something is wrong with the "path". I have tried `path=/`before. The initial page has a path like: http://domain-name/directory/the-first-page/ .

**Update 2:**
Another info that may be relevant is that the intial page is not SSL-encrypted, but the external page is SSL-encrypted, and the final page isn't.

Answer (score 0):

```
 var d = new Date();
 var days=5;
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (days*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = ""+d.toUTCString();

document.cookie =
        'member_id=' + $('#member_input').val() + //getting the value, setting the cookie
        '; expires=' + expires +
        '; path=/';
```

use date to set the expiry of the cookie and use this formula to set number of day for the expiry

Comment: I got the same result - but I just realized that the last page is in a different directory (I updated the original post)